# How to connect Desktop Flutter App to Firestore using Firedart plugin

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have been looking around all over the internet but unfortunately there is no clear way of connecting a desktop flutter app to firestore using firedart plugin